# Estimating values of a function by considering the graph of its derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

Let the function $f$ be continuous in $[0,4]$ and differentiable in $(0,4)$. Looking at the graph I am so tempted to say that $f(2)=f(4)$ but I guess $f(2)>f(4)$ is correct. I know this is very simple but some insight is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have
$$
f(4) - f(2) = \int_{t=2}^{4}f'(t) < 0,
$$
so your guess is right.

Comment: Wow never looked at it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the plot of $f'$ between $2$ and $4$. It's negative between those points. This means that the slope of $f(x)$ is negative as we move rightward across the interval $(2,4)$. This means that $f(x)$ will $\mathbf{decrease}$ as $x$ moves rightward from $2$ to $4$.